# Jackson JSON: how to deserialize double to class using setter in java

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize (and serialize) something like:

```
{"myVal":1.0}
```

To(from) MyClass (without messing with complex structure of myVal):

```
public class MyClass {
    private MyValue myVal;

    public Double getMyVal() {
        return myVal.getVal();
    }

    public void setMyVal(Double val) {
        myVal = new MyValue();
        myVal.setVal(val);
    } 
}
```

but deserialization throws exception like

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type "MyValue"
```

I tried various annotations but without success.

Comment: Please provide an MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a [*custom deserializer*](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization). Essentially, you can write a custom deserializer that will create a `MyValue` object instead of having to modify said object to make it into a Java bean.